# How do I create a website with multiple pages that the user can access without reloading the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The website is very simple and consists of just 4 pages that all use the same template. I want the user to be able to seamless browse through the different pages by clicking the links on top without reloading anything.

Basically, the entire website should be loaded when a user first lands on the website. Then, after the first page finishes loading, a user can click any link on top, and the new web page will display without reloading anything.

I know I am supposed to use Jquery or Javascript to accomplish this. I'm just not sure what Jquery / Javascript function does this. All the web pages are very simple and similar.

Comment: If you know it takes JavaScript to do this, why don't you Google it and start there?

Comment: I don't want to use AJAX. And I'm not sure what to Google. I already tried googling "Load multiple pages javascript", which didn't seem to address my question fully.

Comment: If you know better "Google" search terms I can use, please feel free to share. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you don't want to use the tool built for the job how do expect to get it done?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp: visit this site to understand ajax.

Comment: `^` - Don't. Just use jQuery AJAX. It's easier to understand for new players.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you just want to assign each "page" (which will actually just be divs or something like that) an id or class and then in your CSS file, set each of them to display:none. Then use jQuery's .show() and .hide() to show or hide them.

To be more specific, you want to bind some handlers to the navigation, e.g. For the home navigation item:

```
$("#my-home-nav").click(function(){
    $("#my-home-div").show(); // or .fadeIn(), etc.
    $("#my-about-div").hide();
    $("#my-contact-div").hide();
});
```

The above might make writing this kind of verbose if there were a lot of pages, and it would be somewhat difficult to add additional pages. Something like the below might make it easier to add additional pages:

```
var pageNames = ["home", "about", "contact"];
var namespace = "my";

var pages = pageNames.map(function(pageName) {
    return {
        nav: pageNameSelector(pageName, "nav"),
        div: pageNameSelector(pageName, "div")
    };
});

pages.forEach(function(page) {
    page.nav.click(function() {
        clearPages(pages);
        page.div.show();
    });
});

function pageNameSelector(pageName, type) {
    return $(["#" + namespace, pageName, type].join("-"));
}

function clearPages(pages) {
    pages.forEach(function(page) {
        page.div.hide();
    });
}
```

So then all you would have to do is follow that same convention for identifying additional pages where the ids for the nav/div are given like `NAMESPACE-PAGENAME-TYPE` and when you add an additional page name to `pageNames`, the show/hide functionality would just work.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much describing tabs.  You can use jQuery UI Tabs for this: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Or you can roll your own tabs, too - hide the content, then reveal the right content when a link is clicked, hiding all the others.  I tend to build my own because I can make it work exactly as I want and it hasn't got any extra overhead "stuff" it doesn't need.  If you try and it doesn't work, there's always the jQuery UI to fall back on.

Comment: Without some kind of fragment identifier or history manipulation, you're creating an accessibility problem. What if I hit the back button, expecting it to go back to the last tab? What if I see some content on one of the tabs and try to share a link to it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a JQuery plugin called [JQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org) that gives provides an easy interface for common web design functionality, including what you need. Specifically, the [Tabs](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html) feature allows you to load certain `<div>`'s when links in a `<ul>` are clicked. From http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html:

```
<!-- the tabs -->
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- tab "panes" -->
<div class="panes">
    <div>First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div>
    <div>Second tab content</div>
    <div>Third tab content</div>
</div>
```

The only JavaScript you need is:

```
// perform JavaScript after the document is scriptable.
$(function() {
    // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
```

This will make all of the links in `ul.tabs` navigate to each of the divs that are *directly* children of `div.panes` (hence the `>` - make sure it's there if you want that).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use frames. One web page may contain multiple frames, and you can also make some of them invisible (include a switch). Check this link: http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jframe1.htm